# Microsoft CRM 4.0 View: How can I create a complete new one?

Tags: view, dynamics-crm, customization, dynamics-crm-4

I want to create a complete new View for Microsoft CRM 4.0. I don't want to create a custom view and select which columns show.

I want to create a view that represent the result of a specific join between my entity and another entity.

Is it possible to create it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is always going to ask you what columns to show, its part of it's xml query syntax. There is no way to get around this.

If your creating a lot of views you can attempt to export the customization xml file and copy the xml nodes, then import the customizations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a custom view by getting FetchXML from an Advanced find and show in an IFRAME.